# Concentration of coordinatewise Lipschitz function

Tags: probability, lipschitz-functions, gaussian, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be coordinatewise $1$-Lipschitz, i.e $|f(x')-f(x)| \le |x'_k-x_k|$ whenever $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $x' = (x'_1,\ldots,x_n')$ are two vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ which only differ in their $k$th coordinates. Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be a random vector in $\mathbb R^n$ with coordinates drawn iid from $\mathcal N(0,1)$ and define $Y:=f(X)$

> **Question.** What is a non-trivial concentration inequality for $Y$ ?

**Note.** The particular function I have in mind is $f(x) := \max_{i \ne j} |x_i - x_j|$.

### Observation

If one is too lazy, one can observe that any such $f$ is $n$-Lipschitz w.r.t the euclidean norm, and so by a standard result, we get
$\mathbb P(|Y - \mathbb E[Y]| \ge t) \le 2e^{-t^2/(2n^2)}$. I'm hoping for a concentration inequality with a much better dependence on the dimension $n$. It is in this sense that I mean "nontrivial concentration inequality".

Comment: If in "Observation" you meant McDiarmid's inequality, then there's a mistake. If there's no any typo, then why observation is true? In McDiarmid's inequality $f$ is Lipschitx w.r.t. some distance, which is not euclidean.

Comment: @BotnakovN. I assume this refers to the Gaussian concentration inequality.

Comment: @BotnakovN Nope, I didn't mean McDiarmid's inequality. This is a standard result on the concentration of Lipschitz functions of independent Gaussian random variables. E.g see Theorem 8 of this blogpost https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/ (contains a proof).

Comment: @dohmatob Have you looked at, e.g., Corollary 2.1 [in these notes](https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/386/Concentration.pdf) (seems to give a linear dependence on $n$, using McDiarmid to derive a result)

Comment: @ClementC. Indeed it does. They must be doing something slightly more clever than my somewhat blind approach. Thanks!

Comment: From my cursory reading, they are using McDiarmid on Rademacher rv's, then using the tensorization trick ("bits to Gaussian"). McDiarmid is weaker than Gaussian concentration when you deal directly with Lipschitzness in Euclidean distance, but here you don't, so McDiarmid turns out to be more useful.

Comment: OK, makes sense . Thanks!

Comment: This also should be tight by taking $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)= \sum_{k=1}^n x_i$, @dohmatob.

Comment: Indeed, since then $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i  \sim \mathcal N(0,n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a tighter dependence on $n$ by using McDiarmid *for Rademacher r.v.'s* then using a standard "tensorization trick" to have the result carry over to the Gaussian measure: essentially, looking at $(\{-1,1\}^m)^n$ and define your new function $g\colon \{-1,1\}^{mn} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
g(x) = f\!\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{k=1}^m x_k, \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{k=m1}^{2m} x_k, \dots, \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{k=(n-1)m+1}^{nm} x_k\right)
$$
and applying McDiarmid to $g$ (which is $1/\sqrt{m}$-Lipschitz in each coordinate), before letting $m\to\infty$. See, e.g., Corollary 2.1 in [these lecture notes](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/386/Concentration.pdf).

This gives that, under your assumption of coordinate-wise $1$-Lipschitzness of $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and under the standard Gaussian distribution,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ |f(X)-\mathbb{E}[f(X)] | \geq t \} \leq 2e^{-2t^2/n} \tag{$\dagger$}
$$

Moreover, this bound is tight, as one can check by taking $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ (as then $f(X)$ is itself Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $n$).